# How to build android project pulled from Git repo using Intellij IDEA 15.2 on OS X

Tags: android, git, macos, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

Folks,
I have a Windows machine and a MAC machine. The windows machine contains a happy and functioning Android project. I want to develop the same Android project on MAC machine. Thus, I uploaded the project onto a git-server, and then cloned the project repo to MAC machine. However, the gradle on mac machine is not happy with the project. It gives me error message:

> Information:Gradle: Executing tasks: [:client:assembleDebug]
>   Information:Kotlin: Kotlin JPS plugin is disabled
>   Information:16/1/20 下午4:57 - Compilation completed with 2 errors and 0 warnings in 8s 478ms
>   Error:Gradle: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
>   Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':client:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Crunching Cruncher abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png failed, see logs

I believe that the Android framework should be OK, because I can run a "Hello World" app on my device from the MAC. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in Gradle script, where the build tool version is incorrect in the script I load from remote git repo.